# QPushButton not displaying

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I started reading the zetcode tutorial for PyQt4 (http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/) and I was doing the tooltip part and all I did was copy and paste this bit of code. When I went to run it, the push button did not display in the window. Any reason as to why this might be? new to PyQt4 and Qt in general.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button, self')
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace following line:

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button, self')
```

with:

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know how that ended up happening when all I did was copy paste it. Should have seen that myself sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button, self')
```

supposed to be:

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
```